# Gradient Descent algorithm resulting in Nan's

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement a Gradient Descent algorithm in Python but I'm having a hard time getting it done. I have a sparse matrix (X_sparse), in which I'm trying to find two matrices (p and q) whose product approximates well the entries on the non-zero entries of the Sparse Matrix. So, in order to find the vectors p[i] and q[j] who compose the matrices p and q, I'm applying the Gradient Descent.

Here's the code:

```
def Gradient_Descent(X_sparse):
n_factors = 10
n_steps = 10
alpha = 0.01

#initializing the vectors randomly:
p = np.random.normal(0, .1, (X_sparse.shape[0], n_factors))
q = np.random.normal(0, .1, (X_sparse.shape[1], n_factors))

for k in range(0,n_steps):
    for (i,j) in zip(X_sparse.nonzero()[0],X_sparse.nonzero()[1]):
        err = X_sparse[i,j] - np.dot(p[i],q[j])
        p[i] = p[i] + alpha*q[j]*err
        q[j] = q[j] + alpha*p[i]*err
return (p,q)
```

When called, this function returns for both p and q:

```
array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
   [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
   [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
   ...,
   [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
   [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
   [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]])
```

(at least p and q with the right shape of each one). Can somebody help me figure why?

Edit: I get these warnings as well

```
C:\Users\Bernard\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:14: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
C:\Users\Bernard\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:13: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply del sys.path[0]
C:\Users\Bernard\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:13: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add del sys.path[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should multiply whole row and column in np.dot() no just single element. And also train for longer iterations.

Your error is because of large numbers in X_sparse which results in exploding gradients problem. So you should normalize you data.

Use this:

```
def Gradient_Descent(X):
    X_sparse = X/np.max(X)           # normalizing values
    print(X_sparse)
    n_factors = 10
    n_steps = 10000                  # optimized
    alpha = 0.1                      # optimized
    
    #initializing the vectors randomly:
    p = np.random.normal(0, .01, (X_sparse.shape[0], n_factors))
    q = np.random.normal(0, .01, (n_factors, X_sparse.shape[1]))      # changed so as to follow matrix multiplication rule
    
    for k in range(0,n_steps):
        for (i,j) in zip(X_sparse.nonzero()[0],X_sparse.nonzero()[1]):
            err = X_sparse[i,j] - np.dot(p[i, :],q[:, j])              # multiply whole row and column
            p[i, :] = p[i, :] + alpha*q[:, j]*err                      # update whole row and column
            q[:, j] = q[:, j] + alpha*p[i, :]*err                      # update whole row and column
    print(np.dot(p, q)) 
    p = p*np.sqrt(np.max(X))                         # matrix multiplication rule for normalized values
    q = q*np.sqrt(np.max(X))                         # matrix multiplication rule for normalized values
    return (p,q)
```

Since, at starting, we are dividing by np.max(X), so we should multiply p and q by np.sqrt(np.max(X)).

It works for me:

```
Input: 
    X = np.array([[12, 0],
                  [16, 11],
                  [0, 230]])
    p, q = Gradient_Descent(X)
    print(np.dot(p, q))
Output:
    array([[ 12.        ,  16.12096025],
           [ 16.        ,  11.        ],
           [ 26.17067276, 230.        ]])
```

Comment: Hi, Rahul. It didn't work for me. Still getting Nan's with this approach. I don't know if it matters but my Sparse Matrix has shape of (69600, 9927)

Comment: Edit: for n_steps = 2 it worked. Not really sure why it keeps returning Nan's after more iterations.

Comment: Could you provide some sample X_sparse for which it's not working.